# Subtract aggregate function from each column in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to combine an aggregate function from the corresponding column for each column of a SQL table. For instance, if I want to subtract the average of each column, I can do it with a subquery for each column as

```
SELECT 
       col1 - (SELECT AVG(col1) FROM table), 
       col2 - (SELECT AVG(col2) FROM table),
       col3 - (SELECT AVG(col3) FROM table)
FROM table;
```

However, if there are many columns in the table this is cumbersome, and requires to write column names one by one. Is there a way to simplify the code, or to make it more clear with aliases?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT col1 - AVG(col1) OVER (),
       col2 - AVG(col2) OVER (),
       col3 - AVG(col3) OVER ()
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to compare each individual with the mean of all the values.

```sql
SELECT
t1.uid
t1.col1 - t2.col1avg as col1dev
t1.col2 - t2.col2avg as col2dev
t1.col3 - t2.col3avg as col3dev
FROM
table t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
     AVG(col1) as col1avg,
     AVG(col2) as col2avg,
     AVG(col3) as col3avg FROM table) t2 ON ( t1.uid = t2.uid)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the .uid...I don't have it in my table. Do I have to create a unique identifier manually in the table first? Anyhow, I think there is a small typo in your code, otherwise the first select create three identical columns with different name

Comment: which is the name of your unique identifier in your table? you must have a col1, col2, col3 value for each ...?

Comment: Sorry, probably I wasn't clear. I mean in your code there is a join over a "column" called uid, as  t1.uid=t2.uid. What I don't understand is where this come from as I don't have it neither in the original t1 table nor in t2

Comment: so which is the structure of you table? do you only have a col1,col2 and col3 and nothing more?

Comment: yes, indeed. As far as I understand your code would require a uid column that has to be created in t1, but also has to be created in t2 (where you need the same uid of table t1 and columns where the average value is a constant). In this case I would use an inner join

Comment: Often having to perform the same operation on many columns is a sign of not normalizing your data. Cumbersome queries are a price to be paid. Are you paying that price?